# Is there a HTML/CSS way to display HTML tags without parsing?

Tags: html, css, character-encoding, special-characters

Is there any way that I could display HTML tags without parsing? Tags like `XMP` worked before perfectly but now it's replaced with `PRE` that isn't so cool. Take a look at this example:

```
//This used to NOT PARSE HTML even if you used standard < and >.
<XMP>
<a hred="http://example.com">Link</a>
</XMP>

//New PRE tag requires &lt; and &gt; as replacement for < and >.
<PRE>
&#60;a href="http://example.com"&#62;Link&#60;/A&#62;
</PRE>
```

What I'm looking for is equivalent of old XMP tag. New PRE tag will parse code.

Comment: Was there any specific use case you were looking for, or do you just want to avoid having to encode characters?

Comment: @Moses I just want to be able to freely use `<pre>` and/or `<code>` tags on my website without necessity to convert anything (like `<` to `&lt;`). I'd like them to display HTML/CSS code without parsing.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use a `script` element with its `type` set to denote plain text, and set its `display` property to `block`. This only affects the parsing behavior: no markup (tags or entity or character references) is recognized, except for the end tag of the element itself `</script>`. (So it is not *quite* the same as `xmp`, where the recognized tag is `</xmp>`.) You can separately make white space handling similar to that of `xmp` and `pre` and/or set the font the monospace as in those elements by default.

Example:

```
<style>
    script {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

Then within document body:

```
<script type="text/plain">
    <i>&eacute;</i>
</script>
```

Tested on newest versions of IE, Chrome, Firefox, Opera. Didn’t work in IE 8 and IE 7 emulation on IE 9, but that’s probably a bug in the emulation.

However, I don’t see why you would use this instead of `xmp`, which hasn’t stopped working. It’s not in the specs, but if you are worried about that, you should have always been worried. Mentioned in HTML 2.0 (the first HTML spec ever) as avoidable, it was deprecated in HTML 3.2 and completely removed in HTML 4.0 (long ago: in 1997).

The `xmp` is making a comeback rather than dying. The W3C HTML5 (characterized as the current HTML specification by W3C staff) declares `xmp` as obsolete and non-conforming, but it also imposes a [requirement](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#other-elements-attributes-and-apis) on browsers: “User agents must treat `xmp` elements in a manner equivalent to `pre` elements in terms of semantics and for purposes of rendering. (The parser has special behavior for this element though.)” The old parsing behavior is thus not explicitly required, but clearly implied.

Comment: But i am not able to append like that in jquery!!
      `$("#htmltest").html("<script type='text/plain'>"+unescape(escape(testvar))+"</script>"); `

Comment: No significant change @jukka-k-korpela

Comment: you can surround `<script>` tag with `<pre>` to keep indent

Answer (score 6):

I personally think using the `<code> </code>` tags only works in Dream Weaver and the tag `<xmp> </xmp>` never stopped working unless you put in `</xmp>` it works fine. Using `<textarea> </textarea>` makes it so that others can edit your code on the website or the page so I recommend that the tag `<xmp> </xmp>` is still used and that that tag still lives on.

Answer (score 5):

The modern way is to use textarea with (boolean) attribute readonly. You could use XMP, but that is deprecated, so it may eventually stop being supported.  
example:

```
<textarea readonly='true'>
    <p>This is some text</p>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Please try to provide a specific example for his problem, or else this could easily be a comment on his post.

Comment: This answer worked very fine for me, thanks!! I just recomment to set the textarea css `display: none` because there is absolutely no reason to display everything to users!

Answer (score 2):

And then... a few years go by, I have the same problem while converting my blog from wordpress to a vuejs spa backed by lambda and dynamodb.

And the answer is; at least in my situation. Escape the entity.

`&lt;` becomes `&amp;lt;`

`&gt;` becomes `&amp;gt;`

etc. etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great (and unconventional) answer! In my particular case, it was just what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't.

In theory you could use a CDATA block, but no browser supports that in text/html mode.

Use character references.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be more complex, another way is to create a custom tag using jQuery. For this example, I used `<noparse>`.

```
$('noparse').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('tagchecked') != 'true'){ //checks if already changed tag
        $(this).text($(this).html()).attr('tagchecked', 'true'); //makes the html into plaintext
    }
});
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyGamer14/6eBxK/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the html iframe tag and put the text you like to display in the src attribute. you only have to url or base64 encode it first.

```
example (urlencoded):
<iframe src="data:text/plain,%22%3Chello%3E%22"></iframe>

example (base64):
<iframe src="data:text/plain;base64,IjxoZWxsbz4i"></iframe>

Result displayed as:
"<hello>"
```

Answer (score -1):

Technically you could use `<textarea>`, but it would require that there be no `</textarea>` tag in the code you are trying to show. It'd just easier to escape the `<`.

Comment: The use of `textarea` does not switch off all HTML parsing: character and entity references are still parsed. E.g., `<textarea>&eacute;</textarea>` displays é whereas `<xmp>&eacute;</xmp>` displays `&eacute;`.

Answer (score -1):

Well, one way would be to use jQuery.  the jQuery .text() method will encode special characters.  And the original un-encoded text will remain if you view source.

```
<div id="text">
    <a href="">This is an anchor</a>
</div>

<script>
    var t = $('#text'); t.html(t.text());
</script>
```

Comment: That will show a serialisation of the DOM created from the HTML, not the original HTML. It will also show a flash of rendered content.

Comment: @Quentin - True, though in most cases those would be the same.  And there are ways around the flashing.