# JS to show HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I have a test page like this:

index.html:

```
<p>This is how you should write paragraphs in HTML:</p>

<div id="example">

    <p>Foo</p>

</div>
```

If I open this page in the browser, I want to see both text and tags:

```
This is how you should write paragraphs in HTML:

<p>Foo</p>
```

How it may be automatically done with js?

Yes, I can manually replace `<` and `>` by `&lt;` and `&gt;`, but I want to avoid manual work.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities) might be interesting for you

Comment: Do you still want the `<p>`-Tag to be a `<p>`-Tag (as in `<p>&lt;p&gt; [...] &lt;/p&gt;</p>`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `htmlEncode` method as

```
function htmlEncode ( html )
{
    html = $.trim(html);
    return html.replace(/[&"'\<\>]/g, function(c) 
    {
          switch (c) 
          {
              case "&":
                return "&amp;";
              case "'":
                return "&#39;";
              case '"':
                return "&quot;";
              case "<":
                return "&lt;";
              default:
                return "&gt;";
          }
    });
};
```

Now encode the value as

```
$( "#example" ).html( htmlEncode ( $( "#example" ).html() ) );
```

**DEMO**

```js
function htmlEncode ( html )
    {
     html = $.trim(html);
     return html.replace(/[&"'\<\>]/g, function(c) 
     {
        switch (c) 
        {
         case "&":
           return "&amp;";
         case "'":
           return "&#39;";
         case '"':
           return "&quot;";
         case "<":
           return "&lt;";
          default:
           return "&gt;";
        }
     });
    };

    $( "#example" ).html( htmlEncode ( $( "#example" ).html() ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is how you should write paragraphs in HTML:</p>

<div id="example">

    <p>Foo</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here: [Is there a HTML/CSS way to display HTML tags without parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673978/is-there-a-html-css-way-to-display-html-tags-without-parsing)

```
<style>

script
{
    display: block;
}

</style>

<div id="example">
    Then within document body:
<script type="text/plain">
    <p>Foo</p>
</script>
</div>
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9vkowqb3/

Answer (score 0):

Check the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u8hhz5ms/) 
HTML:

```
<p>This is how you should write paragraphs in HTML:</p>

<div id="example">

</div>
```

JS:

```
var text = document.createTextNode('<p>Stuff</p>');
document.getElementById('example').appendChild(text);
```