# For innerHTML, Is there any way to distinguish if the content is a string inside angle brackets ("<", ">") or a real html tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show a string as innterHTML of a div, but inside this string, it may contains a real html, like `<h1>apple</h1>`, so it will show 'apple' with heading 1, which is what I want. However, if this string contains some letters, which is inside angle brackets, like`<bookName>`. what I want to see is the real string `'<bookName>'`show out, but this innerHTML will take this  as a  html tag, which is not. 
So is there a way to ditingguish which letters inside angle brackets becoming a real html tag or which letters inside angle brackets is just part of this string? 
Example: Given string`"<h1>apple<h1> is a <bookName>"`, what I want to see in web page is `"apple is a <bookName>"`, but this apple is in Heading 1.

Comment: Please show your code. It is not clear how you want such "strings" to be parsed in the html. Do you mean that you are dynamically adding this strings in the html through javascript or are you just meaning to work with only html. If you only meant working with only html, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673978/is-there-a-html-css-way-to-display-html-tags-without-parsing

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some research on escape characters, its a special character or string of characters that tells the code to read the next symbol as a plain old ASCII character and not any special code indicator

Comment: Where does your data come from? You should have done the sanitization server-side. (every special characters in text should be replaced by their HTMLEntities. e.g `<` => '&lt;`). It is already too late when it comes to your front-end code.

Comment: @Kaiido data comes from server, if every special characters has been replaced, when UI get it, UI still confuse which brackets are real html tags, which are just a brackets with letters inside, right?

Comment: And before being on the server, where did it came from? You must know at input which should be part of the text and which should be part of the markup. You'll encode only the text part, the markup part will stay as markup `<>`.

Comment: @Kaiido oh I see what you mean now. Server get it from other server API, maybe I should research that server’ s API to find a way to distinguish them.

Comment: @LyuChang It can be manipulated either on the server side or the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the children collection

```js
console.log(isTextNode('txt'));
console.log(isTextNode('child'));

function isTextNode(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).children.length === 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="txt">text</div>
<div id="child"><span>child</span></div>
```